# Solution of the ODE: $\displaystyle\ddot{x}(t)=-\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k\left[x(t)-x_k\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I had to solve the ODE: 
$$\displaystyle\ddot{x}(t)=-\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k\left[x(t)-x_k\right]$$
where $\alpha_k$ and $x_k$ are constant.
I solved it for $N=2$ and $N=3$. So for induction I get for a generic $N$, the solution:
$$x(t)=c_1\sin\left(\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k}t\right)+c_2\sin\left(\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k}t\right)+\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^N(\alpha_k x_k)}{\sum_{k=1}^N(\alpha_k)}$$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constant depending on the initial values. Is this solution correct?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems correct. I took your solution into the equation and verfied it ... maybe you can also do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ODE rewrites as
$$
\ddot{x}(t)=-x(t) \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k}_{\omega^2} + \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k x_k}_{F} \; ,
$$
which is of the form
$$
\ddot{x}(t) + \omega^2\, {x}(t) = F \, .
$$
The solutions are
$$
x(t) = c_1\cos (\omega t) + c_2\sin (\omega t) + \frac{F}{\omega^2} .
$$